# Webapp to track changes in a document, without login/account but with nickname and allows all markup to be viewed

Tags: google-drive

Looking to collaborate on a document with a team.  Google Docs would be perfect, however the users do not all have Google accounts.

Ideally want the document to be editable by all users with the link (or password), however its important that it attributes changes to a specific user nickname, rather than just 'anonymous'

Finally - I'd like to be able to see all markup similar to "ORIGINAL: SHOW MARKUP" in Microsoft Word.

It's important that all users can see all changes that have been made against the original, rather than having one live version that only reflects the changes made by the latest editor.

37Signals' [Writeboard](http://writeboard.com) does the first part, but not the second.  Each time changes are saved, it becomes the latest live version.

I've also looked at EtherPad-powered services - which also will only let you edit off the latest revision, rather than keeping the original for all the users to edit off of

Comment: Well on Google Docs you can find all these features except the login part, and I don't think that you will find something that descent without any login (or a simple password which will be set by you, I guess).

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [TypeWith.me](http://typewith.me/), which has most of the features that you want. It is based on the [EtherPad](http://etherpad.com/), which was eventually acquired by Google and became an open source [project](http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/).

Few other clones based on EtherPad:

- [Sync.in](http://sync.in/)
- [iEtherPad.com](http://ietherpad.com/)
- [ParatePad.net](http://piratepad.net/)

Comment: Thanks - edited the question to indicate I've looked at EtherPad already - it is similar to Google Docs and Writeboard as it only lets you show the latest revisions, rather than the "ORIGINAL: SHOW MARKUP" feature that I'm looking for